# Removing a key=>value pair from a 3D associative array - PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

The 3D assoc. array looks like below.

```
Array 
( 
    [COL] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 775.00 
                            [name] => COL 
                        ) 
                    [1] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 26 
                            [user_name] => John Doe 
                            [amount] => 555.00 
                            [name] => COL 
                        ) 
                ) 
    [RA. 20%] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 110.00 
                            [name] => RA. 20% 
                        ) 
                ) 
    [BS] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 444.00 
                            [name] => BS 
                        ) 
                ) 
)
```

I want to remove the the last `key=>value` pair of each inner most array. (want to remove the key value pair that has [name] for the key)
The result should look like the array below.

```
Array 
( 
    [COL] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 775.00
                        ) 
                    [1] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 26 
                            [user_name] => John Doe 
                            [amount] => 555.00
                        ) 
                ) 
    [RA. 20%] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 110.00
                        ) 
                ) 
    [BS] => Array 
                ( 
                    [0] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [emp_num] => 1000001 
                            [user_name] => Test User 
                            [amount] => 444.00
                        ) 
                ) 
)
```

I wrote a function to do this.

```
<!-- language: php -->    
function remove_name_from_psa($psa_array){

            foreach( $psa_array as $key=>$value ) {
                foreach( $value as $key2=>$value2 ){
                    foreach( $value2 as $key3=>$value3 ){                    
                         if( $key3 != 'name') {
                            $psa_name_removed[$key][$value[$key2][$value2[$key3]]] = $value3;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $psa_name_removed;
        }
```

The returned array is this, which is obviously not what I need.

```
Array ( [COST OF LIVING] => Array 
                   ( [] => 555.00 ) 
        [RENT ALLOW. 20%] => Array 
                   ( [] => 110.00 ) 
        [BASIC SALARY] => Array 
                   ( [] => 444.00 ) 
      )
```

And there are lots of undefined offset and undefined index notices.
`$psa_name_removed[$key][$value[$key2][$value2[$key3]]] = $value3;`  //is this the line I am doing the mistake? Or is the whole method a mistake? :-P
How can I get this to work? Can anyone help?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function remove_name_from_psa($psa_array){

    foreach( $psa_array as $key => $value ) {
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ){
            unset( $psa_array[$key][$key2]['name'] );
        }
    }
    return $psa_array;

}
```

Comment: No need for `isset`. Just `unset`. Done.

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that unset wouldn't throw a notice if the key in question didn't exist. Maybe I'm just overly cautious :p

Answer (score 1):

Wee, functional solution!

```
$array = array_map(function ($i) {
    return array_map(function ($j) {
        return array_diff_key($j, array_flip(array('name')));
    }, $i);
}, $array);
```

More traditional solution:

```
foreach ($array as &$i) {
    foreach ($i as &$j) {
        unset($j['name']);
    }
}
```

Note the `&` in `as &$i`. Use this *reference* to modify the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as &$foo){
    foreach($foo as &$bar){
        unset($bar['name']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To truly unset the last element in a 3D array your would do this:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        array(1, 2, 3),
    ),
);

foreach ($data as $i1 => $j1) {
    foreach ($j1 as $i2 => $j2) {
        end($j2);
        unset($data[$i1][$i2][key($j2)]);
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```

See it in action here:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/CbgnVf

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_name_from_psa( $psa_array ){
    foreach( $psa_array as $key => $value ) {
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) {
            array_pop( $psa_array[$key][$key2] );
        }
    }
    return $psa_array;
}
```